# List of Lists of Coordinates

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and am struggling with a task that I assume is an extremely simple one for an experienced programmer.

I am trying to create a list of lists of coordinates for different lines. For instance:

list = [ [(x,y), (x,y), (x,y)], [Line 2 Coordinates], ....]

I have the following code:

```
masterlist_x = list(range(-5,6))

oneline = []

data = []

numberoflines = list(range(2))

i = 1 

for i in numberoflines: 

    slope = randint(-5,5)
    y_int = randint(-10,10)


    for element in masterlist_x: 

       oneline.append((element,slope * element + y_int))

    data.append(oneline)
```

The output of the variable that should hold the coordinates to one line (oneline) holds two lines:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6VRy.png)

I know this is an issue with the outer looping mechanism, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: You forgot to reset the `oneline` list to be empty again before looping through again. Adding `oneline = []` to the beginning of your first for loop should fix it. Having inside the for loop also helps indicate that you intend to start with an empty list each iteration.

Comment: Glad you got your question answered, @Sam. In the future please do not link to images of text, but copy-paste code or output into your question (just format them as `code` to preserve layout). Linking to images makes your question much harder to read and answer.

Answer (score 0):

@khuynh is right, you simply had the `oneline = []` in wrong place, you put all the coords in one line.

Also, you have a couple unnecessary things in your code:

- you don't need `list()` the `range()`, you can just iterate them directly with `for`
- also you don't need to declare the `i` for the `for`, it does it itself
- that `i` is not actually used, which is fine. Python convention for unused variables is `_`

Fixed version:

```py
from random import randint

masterlist_x = range(-5,6)
data = []
numberoflines = range(2)

for _ in numberoflines: 
    oneline = []

    slope = randint(-5,5)
    y_int = randint(-10,10)

    for element in masterlist_x: 
       oneline.append((element,slope * element + y_int))

    data.append(oneline)

print(data)
```

Also on-line there where you can run it: https://repl.it/repls/GreedyRuralProduct

I suspect the whole thing could be also made with much less code, and in a way in a simpler fashion, as a list comprehension ..

UPDATE: the inner loop is indeed very suitable for a list comprehension. Maybe the outer could be made into one as well, and the whole thing could two nested list comprehensions, but I only got confused when tried that. But this is clear:

```py
from random import randint

masterlist_x = range(-5,6)
data = []
numberoflines = range(2)

for _ in numberoflines: 
  slope = randint(-5,5)
  y_int = randint(-10,10)

  oneline = [(element, slope * element + y_int)
             for element in masterlist_x]

  data.append(oneline)

print(data)
```

Again on repl.it too: https://repl.it/repls/SoupyIllustriousApplicationsoftware

Comment: Thank you so much @khuynh and @antont!!!! I really appreciate your help. I will work on simplifying the code also.

Comment: @Sam updated with a slightly modified version where the inner loop is a list comprehension